# Extjs -panelHeader title alignment

Tags: extjs4

I have a panel with header set to left of panel body

```
    Ext.each(configs, function (config) {
    Ext.createWidget('panel', Ext.applyIf(config, {
        renderTo: 'summaryDiv',
        bodyPadding: 2,
        headerPosition : 'left',
    }));
});
```

what is the config for making the header title of panel to either read up or down?
please see this http://jsfiddle.net/nwMDj/46/

Comment: not really sure what you are asking here?  Do you want to flip the text from reading bottom to top to top to bottom?

Comment: yes i want to flip that title part (bottom to  top) and also to be centered. thanks